# Is 20 MB generally enough for a blog database in SQL Server or MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, blogs, appharbor

I want to deploy my blog on [AppHarbor](http://appharbor.com). But the free size of the database is 20 MB. I am not yet ready to pay $10/month for the 10GB database. My question is: would this be sufficient for a simple blog with one post a week?

I am not going to use any blogging engine. I will write my own engine with just posts in the database. I plan to use [Disqus](http://disqus.com) for comments.

Comment: As long as you don't store images in the database, that sounds totally okay.

Comment: 20MB - How many users are you planning to support and how much data are you planning to add? I think you will overrun the size pretty soon. In around 15-30 days time.

Comment: @Sanchin, I'm not sure what kind of coffee you drink, but 20,000,000 characters is a lot of typing for me.  That's 15 characters A SECOND non-stop for 15 days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's basic math, really.

One post a week of say 10kB per post, would make you last 200 weeks.  Mutatis mutandis:

```
          D bytes per database
---------------------------------------  = weeks per database
(N posts per week) x (S bytes per post)
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be enough. Consider that our blog (wordpress based) has almost 1000 posts and around 1000 comments. And the database is less than 5 MB.

Answer (score 2):

yes, 20MB of data is a **lot** of data (if it's text based).

Answer (score 1):

If you're just using text, no images or media, that should be fine. It takes a lot of text to reach 20MB...

Roughly it gives you 4,194,304 words to play with (given 1 byte per character, average of 5 characters per word)

Comment: 7 bytes per character? How do you get that value?

Answer (score 0):

for images u can use something like photobucket, where only links are to be pasted....
20 MB is a HUGE quantity! I would reckon u start with 1 MB from a weekly basis and then go on to 20 MB, will save a bit of $$